# Setting a user-defined variable from within a SQL Execute Task (SSIS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

This is in SQL Server 2005 SSIS:

I am kind of new to the SSIS thing. Is it possible to 'set' a package level user defined variable in TSQL or the Execute SQL Task? I understand how to map a result from a single rowset query. But let's say I want to map 3 variables in a single task?

Consider the following :

```
DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(255)

SET @Table1 = 'Z_Cisco_CallDetail_' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0))))

--create table

DECLARE @Table2 VARCHAR(255)

SET @Table2 = 'Z_Cisco_AgentConnDetail_' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0))))

--create table

DECLARE @Table3 VARCHAR(255)

SET @Table3 = 'Z_AWK_CallRecords_' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0))))

--create table
```

Now I would like to map these 3 dynamic table names to user defined package variables. I saw this syntax used in another thread :

```
SET @[User::Cisco_CallRecords_Tablename] = @Table1
```

But I cannot seem to get it to work. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Jesse

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, if you are trying to put each of the table variables into seperate package level variables. Can you not just have a select query at the end, Select table1,2,3 etc. Then capture those with the single rowset.

Comment: I'm with Peter--use SELECT to set all 3: `DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(255), @Table2 VARCHAR(255), @Table2 VARCHAR(255)`; and then `SELECT @Table1 = 'Z_Cisco_CallDetail_' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0)))), @Table2 = 'Z_Cisco_AgentConnDetail_' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0)))), @Table3 = 'Z_AWK_CallRecords_' + CONVERT(varchar, YEAR(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(YEAR,DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())) + 1, 0))))`

Comment: If your actual question is more about how to pass that to SSIS, then check out this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290211/set-package-variable-to-a-value-from-database?rq=1)